# First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to read data from firebase database using Angularfire2 in Ionic2. My data structure is like user->userID->data. Now I am passing the userID as a parameter in the string as follows

```
this.af.database.object('/user/${af.auth.getAuth().uid}/data');
```

This is throwing me error

> First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain
>   ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

How do I pass the userID parameter in the URL path for firebase?

Comment: Use backticks, not regular quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Backticks was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use of backticks resolved the issue.